# Is an offer of a free utility on topic?

Tags: discussion

I've written some (Windows) software that could be of use to video and audio editors, and I'd like to make it available for free to this community and to Sound Design. Is it permitted to make such an offer, with a description etc, as a 'question' here? Or is there a more appropriate form or forum for such an offer?

I have no agenda: I'm not selling an upgrade version, or advertising any products or services. Just trying to give something away that a few people would find useful.

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: @prof - not yet. I'm still thinking about how to frame a question that acts as an offer. (-:

Comment: For your utility I mean, I'm interested :p

Comment: @prof - I can place this on my own FTP site, but I'm curious if there's a platform for such sharing where a downloader could feel secure that the file has been virus-checked, and where I could get stats on activity?

Comment: If its open source I can recommend using github pages: https://pages.github.com/

Its pretty easy to setup a project page and you get all kinds of stats. Though it doesn't do virus checks, for that you could just link to a virustotal result of your latest binary and offer a SHA256 on your download page, which can be checked by the users and is shown on the scan result page. F.e: https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/98a9ed79a41ec7a75324a2f2ee09f0c931014e901d0be9ed780ca720195c4307/analysis/

Comment: For now, I'm forgoing any 'virus certification', assuming that users will check anyway. For anyone following, here's a link to the utility. Ping me at the address in the Readme with any comments, problems or suggestions. http://bit.ly/Esc_TcGen  I'll put up a 'question' soon.

Answer (score 2):

As a regular contributor, publicizing your program with disclosure is perfectly fine. The big trick is just to find a way to fit it in to a question for it as this is a qa site.  Best bet if you don't know of one, just write your own, ideally so that it can be answered by others as well.

The relevant portion of the Help Center's behavior guidelines.

> Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and
>   tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant
>   answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or
>   website, so be it. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in
>   your answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a
>   mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong
>   reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad
>   sales team for details.

I'd certainly say you are well within it.

Comment: OK, good to know. I don't know if it was clear, but I did ask how this could be done in 'question' format, since there's no actual question involved, only an offer. Just attaching it as an answer to another question wouldn't work all that well.

Comment: @JimMack - perhaps link it in this question to ask for suggestions on how to work it in to a question on the main site.  The easiest way is to ask about software that accomplishes whatever it is your software does and post your own as a possible solution.

Comment: I think I've got a good formulation in mind. My remaining question is whether I can post the same question / answer on both VP and SD, or if there's a way to link one to the other?

Comment: Normally cross posting isn't ideal. What does the program actually do?

Comment: It generates SMPTE/EBU LTC tracks for use in DAWs and video editors, for those platforms that don't have that feature built in. Tracks can also be used with a laptop as a poor-man's portable TCG during shoots etc. It's directly relevant to both communities.

Comment: Yeah, then probably the only difference in the questions you need is "for DAWs" and "for NLEs" on the end of the question.

Comment: in case you don't see the comment above, here's a link to the utility. My address is in the Readme for any comments, problems or suggestions. I'll post the 'questions' soon. http://bit.ly/Esc_TcGen